# How to remove previous installed android app when singature changed?

Tags: android

After changing the signature Keystore from auto-generated one to a really Keystore that on disk via Gradle:

```
signingConfigs{
        key{
            keyAlias 'xxx'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
            storeFile file('D:/work/game/xxx.keystore')
            storePassword 'xxx'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.key
        }
    }
```

There is an error yield when I hit the Play Button on the android studio.

[image]

Note that I have tried:

1. of course press the OK button
2. uninstall the app from my testing device.
3. restart the testing device.

But none of the above works, is this kind of bug of android studio? How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

```
signingConfigs{
        key{
            keyAlias 'xxx'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
            storeFile file('D:/work/game/xxx.keystore')
            storePassword 'xxx'
        }
    }

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.key
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Jijin, what do you mean? Can find any different from your config and the origin config :D